# Change the cursor type system-wide

Tags: linux, types, gtk, cursor

I want to change the cursor type on every opened applications (including the desktop and the panels).
I use GNU/Linux and GTK+.

Here is my attempt to change the cursor type system-wide:

```
List<weak Gdk.Window> windows = Screen.get_default().get_toplevel_windows();
foreach(Gdk.Window window in windows) {
    window.set_cursor(new Cursor(CursorType.PIRATE));
}
```

This code only changes the cursor type on my application window.
How can I change the cursor type on all applications?
Is there a way using GTK+?
If no, how can I do this using Xlib?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't change the mouse cursor in all applications, since each application sets it to whatever it wants anyway.

Longer answer:

Try xsetroot(1)'s -cursor, -cursor_name, -xcf options.

Try using a cursor theme for your preferred desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks. xsetroot seems to do exactly what I want. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work in XFCE. My application runs only on XFCE, so I need a solution that works in this desktop environment. Do you know any alternative that works in XFCE?